# Pre-populating Django-REST endpoints with empty data?

Tags: django, rest, ember.js

In Ruby on Rails, endpoints are automatically create with an empty list. I was wondering if there is equivalent behavior in the Django-REST framework because my ember.js frontend is looking for these endpoints to have some data (could be null), but the interface is not rendering because there is no data at the endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my get function, I just handled it by returning None.